# Preventing operation on a value of custom data type

Tags: haskell

Let's say I create a `Person` type:

```
type Age = Int
type Height = Int
data Person = Person Age Height
```

This is all well, but I'd like to make sure that `Age` and `Height` cannot be added, because that makes no sense. I'd like a compile error when trying to do so.

In it's current form, this does not cause a compile error:

```
stupid (Person age height) = age + height
```

So I think about using `newtype` or even `data` for `Age` and `Height`:

```
newtype Age = Age Int
newtype Height = Height Int
data Person = Person Age Height
```

but still:

```
stupid (Person (Age age) (Height height)) = age + height
```

Is there a way of preventing age and height from being added? Or is what I'm asking for unreasonable?

Comment: Don't export the `newtype`s' constructors.

Answer (score 4):

By unwrapping the newtypes using the constructors `Person` and `Height`, you essentially instruct the compiler to forget the type distinction. That of course makes it legal to write `age + height`, but that's not to blame on the `newtype`s, like it's not to blame on the train driver if you smash the window, jump out and get injured!<sup>†</sup>

The way to prevent such incorrect operation is to not unwrap the newtypes. The following *will* cause an error, if `Age` and `Height` are newtypes:

```
stupid (Person age height) = age + height
```

...not just because `age` and `height` are different types, also because neither actually supports an addition operation (they aren't `Num` instances). Now that's fine, as long as you don't really need to perform *any* operations on these values.

Chances are however that at some point you *will* need to perform some operation on those values. This should *not* require the user to unwrap the actual `newtype` constructors.

For such physical quantities like age and height, there are a few options to do it type-safely:

- Add [`VectorSpace`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space-0.10.4/docs/Data-VectorSpace.html) instances. That will allow you to add one height to another, and scale heights by fractions, but not add a height to something entirely different.

  ```
  import Data.AdditiveGroup
  import Data.VectorSpace

  instance Additive Height where
    Height h₀ ^+^ Height h₁ = Height $ h₀+h₁
    zeroV = Height 0
  instance VectorSpace Height where
    type Scalar Height = Double
    μ *^ Height h = Height . round $ μ * fromIntegral h
  ```

  This simple instance is mighty handy for some science use cases, though probably not that useful for your application.
- Add meaningful unit-specific accessors. In modern Haskell, those would be [lenses](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens):

  ```
  import Control.Lens

  heightInCentimetres :: Lens' Height Int
  heightInCentimetres = lens (\(Height h)->h) (\(Height _) h->Height h)
  ageInYears :: Lens' Age Int
  ageInYears = lens (\(Age a)->a) (\(Age _) a->Age a)
  ```

  This way, if someone needs to work with an actual number of years of someone's age or modify it, they can do so, but they need to be explicit that these are years they're talking about. Of course, accessing the years and height as an integer number again makes it possible to circumvent the type distinction and intermingle ages with height, but this can hardly happen by accident.
- Go all the way to a [library for physical quantities](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/units-defs).

  ```
  import Data.Metrology.SI

  type Height = Length
  type Age = Time
  ```

  This allows you to perform [all kinds of physically legit operations](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/units-2.4/docs/Data-Metrology-Poly.html) while preventing nonsensical ones.

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>Jumping out of a train is actually more dangerous. Rather like [`unsafeCoerce`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Unsafe-Coerce.html#v:unsafeCoerce), which really instructs the compiler to throw all type-safety out of the window and can easily cause crashes or [demons flying out of your nose](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).</sub>

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a common pattern. Put the data type you want to protect into a module of its own:

```
module Quantities (
    Age, Height,   -- NOTE: constructors not exported
    prettyHeight   -- ...
) where

newtype Age = Age Int
newtype Height = Height Int

-- any operations that need to see the int, e.g.:
prettyHeight :: Height -> String
prettyHeight (Height h) = show h ++ "cm"
```

If you do not add an explicit export list to the module, everything will be exported, including the constructors `Age` and `Height`. In the above code, they are *not* exported, thus you can only access the `Int` values from within this module. All operations which actually have to work with the wrapped `Int` have to be in this module.

Now, import this module wherever you need it:

```
module Person where

import Quantities

data Person = Person Age Height

test (Height h) = ()  -- This will not compile, Height not in scope.
```

Any other module except `Quantities` can no longer deconstruct `Height` or `Age`.